# How to make a folder non-readable in Java?

Tags: java, file, windows-7, java-7, folder-permissions

I am trying to create a folder structure as Test1/gotcha/Test3
I want to make Test1 non-reable. The below code does not work:

```
new File("D:\\Test1\\gotcha\\Test3").mkdirs();
PrintWriter writer= new PrintWriter("D:\\Test1\\gotcha\\Test3\\testing.txt");
writer.write("Hello");
writer.close();

File f1= new File("D:\\Test1");
f1.setReadable(false,false);
f1.setExecutable(false,false);
```

I am still able to open the Test1 folder. Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to make folders non-readable in Windows, that is why `setReadable()` in windows does not work.

Answer (score 1):

That cannot be done.

> One way around is to change the file extension of files in that folder to a random name, so that even though the user tries to open it he cannot find an application to do it.

[image]

> Even though he figures out that it can be opened with a text editor, We will encrypt it. So it becomes non-readable.

[image]

This was just a key-substitution cipher. You can use a more complex algorithm like SHA or AES to make it impossible to break.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Demo 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )throws IOException
    {   
        File file = new File("C://temp//Hello1.sddf");// a random extension.
        // creates the file
        file.createNewFile();
        // creates a FileWriter Object
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file); 
        String data = "Hello world!";//hello world is the data.
        // Writes the content to the file
        writer.write(encrypt(data)); 
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }

    private static String encrypt(String data) {// I used a simple cipher I advise to use any other encryption technique.
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String op = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++)
            op += (char)(data.charAt(i) - 5);
        return op;
    }
}
```